# Git hooks to validate remote repository

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to validate git remote repository before the git push event occurs so that only remote urls listed on git hooks will work with git push command else denied?

Comment: To what end? What are you really trying to accomplish here? This is probably an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627).

Comment: I want to implement pre-push git hook so that any accidental push to any remote repository will be denied by the hooks. I want  to create a script hook  to whitelist remote repository url so that push will work for only those urls.

Comment: This is a useful question, an answer would likely provide spin-off solutions too. e.g. Some SaaS repositories lock certain files via git LFS and instead of relying on CI/CD to trap & fail a deployment,  the ability to prevent any such push in the first place would be excellent.